Cannot connect to iPhone / iOS physical device using XCode
At the risk of leaking PI, I see this:

and this:

and of course there are no logs:

I have this error trace:

! Error: iPhone (47) is not available because it is unpaired. Pair
with the device in the Xcode Devices Window, and respond to any
pairing prompts on the device. (code -29)


Developer mode is on on the phone ✔️
iPhone 13 is plugged into my MacBook using a USB cable ✔️

Perhaps I should try bluetooth instead of USB? Not sure why this is hard.
